# Не читается файл jshint в vs code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jshint

"The file is not displayed in the editor because it is either binary or uses an unsupported text encoding. Do you want to open it anyway?" - такой текст выскакивает на открытом файле ._.jshint (mac os)

Comment: Ну так он у вас спрашивает "Do you want to open it anyway?" Нажмите yes

Comment: Нажал, и там выскочили знаки "Mac OS X         2��ATTR��<�<com.apple.quarantineq/0081;5b87e11f;Chrome;E0A1FD3A-5E2D-464F-8557-5B0E31B770E3". Я это удалил и подставил то, что мне нужно. Можно ли так делать?